# How to create sharing link in Sharepoint Online via c#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have an application that works with files in Sharepoint Online using [SharePointPnPCoreOnline](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/3.19.2003?_src=template) library. When a bunch of files are uploaded to some particular folder, I want to create a sharing link for this folder, so everyone in my organization, who has the link, can read these files.

I know how to do so in Sharepoint web UI: go to your site -> Documents -> Select specific folder or file -> Manage Access -> Share -> Select type of access (Everyone in my organization with the link), type in addressee name and click 'Send'. Now I want to do so inside my application.

I have found how to retrieve sharing links for securable objects. You can use `ObjectSharingInformation` class and `Sharing links` property. But I don't have an option to create sharing link.

So is there any chance it is possible programmatically? If it's impossible via SharePointPnPCoreOnline, maybe I can use some API? I tried using Fiddler to catch http requests to Graph API, that were sent while I was creating link in web interface, but couldn't extract any valuable parameters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/s"))
            {
                string s = "password";
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (var c in s)
                    passWord.AppendChar(c);
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

                //ObjectSharingInformation
                ClientResult<string> url = Web.CreateOrganizationSharingLink((ClientRuntimeContext)context, "file url", false);
              context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: This breaks inheritance on the document. Is there a method that does not break inheritance? If unique permission is removed, sharink link gets broken too

Comment: Amazing sharepoint still cant do this. Terrible product for enterprise.